# How to implement Goal Seek excel function in java ? is there any function in apache poi or library which provide this feature for java

Tags: java, excel, spring, apache-poi

how i can implment goal seek excel feature in java. I search on google and also in apache-poi, nothing is found.

Comment: Please provide sample input and desired output in several pairs. Please provide an [mre] of the code environment in which you want the implementation to work, includiing a definition of the API of the function you want to provide. Add a (wrong or empty) function which serves as placeholder for the goalseek function. Without this info, your question is not focused enough on the programming problem you describe and could be closed for that reason. Please provide links to the pages you found during your search and briefly explain why they don't help, otherwise there is not enough effort shown.

Comment: I had to look up what you mean by "goal search". Consider explaining what that is to save others the effort, or you risk that your question is perceived as lacking details or clarify (another close reason).

Comment: Please rephrase the question so as not to ask for recommendation of external resources, because if it is perceived as mainly doing that it is another reason for being closed.

Comment: You did take the [tour], but you seem to have missed [help/on-topic] and [ask], consider rereading please.

Comment: I am asking about Goal Seek Excel functionality in java, Is there any to use goal seek excel functionality in java or implementation for the same.

Comment: Your comment only repeats parts of the question. It does not give the impression that you understood anything I tried to explain to you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers

Comment: Thanks @Yunnosch. I think you don't know about Microsoft Excel Sheet (In windows) and functionality of excel sheet. if you know then you understand this. After that you able to give the answer to this question, that how we can done this functionality automate into java.

Comment: So you expect readers to know the excel function you mention, or to learn about it and based on that understand what it is you actually want to achieve. That is more or less the opposite of what my previous link recommends.